# CASS_ERROR_SERVER_INVALID_QUERY:Could not decode JSON string as a map: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('?'

Tags: json, cassandra, cql

I am trying to use json insert to cassandra table .
i tried a static insertion statment and it worked . but when i try to use binding using " ?" it produced the following error/

```
#define NEW_INSERT_STMT "INSERT INTO test_user_record JSON '{\"user_id\":120,\"first_name\":\"?\",\"last_name\":\"?\",\"company\":\"?\"}'"
```

```
Error:
        File: CassLg2meta.c
        Function: prepare_cass_user_record_table_Insert
        Line: 125
        Message: CASS_ERROR_SERVER_INVALID_QUERY:Could not decode JSON string as a map: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('?' (code 63)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2c37ff3; line: 1, column: 30]. (String was: {"user_id":120,"first_name":?,"last_name":"?","company":"?"})
```

How i can bind variables using json?

Binding Parameters : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.16/topics/basics/binding_parameters/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - JSON parameter is treated as a whole string, and placeholders won't work inside it.

But you really don't need to use JSON here, just use ordinary [INSERT statement](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html#insert-statement) (I think that you need to bind `user_id` as well):

```
INSERT INTO test_user_record (user_id, first_name, last_name, company) 
VALUES (120, ?, ?, ?)
```

and then prepare & bind values to it.

Comment: actually i did it in another way .
i used %s to bind the values then i used "?" to bind the whole json object.
Thanks for the comment.

For more details :https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/2.14/topics/basics/binding_parameters/

Comment: that's not the best approach because: 1) you need to escape your data that you substitute instead of `%s`, otherwise you can get malformed JSON; 2) There is performance overhead because you're sending a bigger string every time, plus Cassandra needs to parse JSON.  If you use `INSERT`, then driver will send only values to the nodes, that is much smaller, and more efficient